# asp.net vnext Tag helpers select option not working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Pl help me to sort out the following issue..

In the View,

```
  <select asp-for="Frequency" asp-items=@ViewBag.Freqs class="form-control" />
```

and in Controller,

```
SelectListItem[] items = {  new SelectListItem() { Text = "item 1", Value= "Nrk" },
                            new SelectListItem() { Text = "item 2", Value= "Nrk 2" }
                            };

        ViewBag.Freqs = items;
        return View();
```

But I am not getting the list in the drop down box.

Comment: I think you're tagging things wrong; I believe this should be [tag:asp.net-mvc-6] [tag:c#-5.0] [tag:asp.net-5]. ("vnext" should not be used. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285353/rename-vnext-tag)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After two days, I found the problem.. the following is worked

```
<select asp-for="Frequency" asp-items=@ViewBag.Freqs class="form-control">
</select>
```

Instead of

```
<select asp-for="Frequency" asp-items=@ViewBag.Freqs class="form-control" />
```

@Matt DeKrey, thanks for pointing the tag issue... I will edit my post as u mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem where my items weren't loading into the select list.

Basically the scaffolding is incorrectly done as:

```
<select asp-for="PropertyId" asp-items="ViewBag.PropertyItems" />
```

When in fact it should fully generate the HTML tag instead:

```
<select asp-for="PropertyId" asp-items="ViewBag.PropertyItems"></select>
```

Had me scratching my head for ages until I noticed that the Create form was working, but was different to the Edit form for the same model.

Annoying - but simple :)

Comment: This was the issue for me!